# Proving results using Fundamental theorem of calculus

Tags: real-analysis

If $g(x) = x$ for $\lvert x \rvert  \ge 1$ and $g(x) = -x$ for $\lvert x \rvert < 1$ and if $G (x) = \frac{\lvert x^2-1 \rvert}{2} $, show that $$\int^3_{-2} g(x) dx  = G(3) - G(-2) = \frac{5}{2}.$$

Just learned the proof of the FTC, but I have no idea how to use it to solve this problem. Helpp!

Comment: I have fixed you MathJax code. Please have a look at the "edit" button to see what I did.

Answer (score 1):

You need to show that $g = G'$. You can show it separately for $|x| < 1$ and $|x| \geq 1$.